# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not working only from one page

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navigation bar with 3 button, saying Home, Films and Genres. Clicking the Genre should open the dropdown with the list of all Genres generated from database and on click to each genre, genrepage containing the list of films of selected genre shows up. But the Genre button (with dropdown) is not working when I am trying to access it from home page. But it works fine for any other pages. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar and any help will be appreciated.

My navbar.php

```
  <?php

 /*
   array of pages
   this builds the navigation list

   format:
    filename => URL name
   */
   $navArray = array(
    'index'         => 'Home',
     'film'         => 'Films',
     'genre'            => 'Genre',
    );

    ?>


    //some html code here

             <?php 
             foreach($navArray as $key => $nav){ 

            //assign active class to currently active page
                if(strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $key)) 
                    $active = ' active';
                else $active = '';

                //if Genre is selected, display dropdown menu
                if($nav=='Genre'){

                    echo '<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Genre<span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">';



            //generate dropdown from database, giving the list of genres
            $queryGenreList="SELECT genre.`name`
                            from genre;
                            ";
            $resultGenreList=$db->query($queryGenreList);


            if($resultGenreList->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $resultGenreList->fetch_assoc()){

                echo '<li><a href="genreInfo.php?name='.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';

                }  
            }
            echo '</ul>
            </li>';

                }

                echo"<li class='nav-item".$active.";'>";
                if($nav!='Genre'){
                    echo"<a class='nav-link' href=".$key.".php>".$nav."</a>";
                }

                }
                ?>


        </li>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, please remove the PHP and provide the generated markup. Another thing, how are you included Bootstrap files? Have you verified that those files are being included on the home page?

Answer (score 4):

If the bootstrap menu is failing to work when navigating away from the homepage, as it sounds like bootstrap.js isn't running on your subpages for the dropdown to work. Check your network tab > js and see if bootstrap.min.js is being loaded in or view the source.